# Basic Java Error

Tags: java

Okay so my code is as follows;

```
  //Variables
  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
  String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
  final String correctAnswer = "RBR";

  //Mastermind program
  //Welcome message
  System.out.println("\nHello " +/*username*/" and welcome to Mastermind!\n");
  System.out.println("##########################################################################\n");
  System.out.println("In this game you have 3 guesses to guess the order of a sequence of letters," +
        "\nthe sequence will consist of the letters R and/or B, in a random order" +
        "\nand you have to guess the order that they are in." +
        "\nYou will be awarded points depending on how many guesses it takes you to" +
        "\nguess the sequence and how many letters you get correct.\n");
  System.out.println("##########################################################################\n");


  //Game start
  System.out.println("Please enter your first guess: " + userGuess);
  if(userGuess.equals(correctAnswer)){
     System.out.println("Congratulations you got it in one go!");
  }
  else{
     System.out.println("Sorry try again");
  }
```

I'm just wondering why when I run it I have to enter my guess straight away, without it running the welcome message, it only runs after I press enter but then either tells me I am correct or incorrect, think it's something to do with .nextLine but I'm not sure?

Comment: that is because you have this: 
  String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
before your welcome message

Comment: Thanks very much ! so just use keyboard.nextLine(); on down in the actual program?

Comment: yup. the nextLine() needs you to press enter before it continues. as long as this line is before the welcome message, this has to be dealt with first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move it down here

```
//Game start
 System.out.println("Please enter your first guess:");
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
 System.out.println("Your guess is: " + userGuess);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move your code:

```
String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```

after the welcome message like this:

```
//Game start
 System.out.println("Please enter your first guess: " + userGuess);
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
 String userGuess = keyboard.nextLine().toUpperCase();
```